# How to convert list to JSON in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a list like this:

```
<ol class="CricketPlayers">
    <li id="1">Player: John, TotalRuns: 4350, AllRounder: false</li>
    <li id="2">Player: Michael, TotalRuns: 8373, AllRounder: true</li>
</ol>
```

I need to convert this into JSON like this:

```
[
    {
        "Player": "John",
        "TotalRuns": 4350,
        "AllRounder": false
    },
    {
        "Player": "Michael",
        "TotalRuns": 8373,
        "AllRounder": true
    }
]
```

*Formatting of JSON is not important.*

Using jQuery etc. is not an option. I am thinking to convert the list into array and then calling `JSON.stringify`. But I not sure if that will work because there can be many items in the list.

Comment: What's the specific issue? You'll need to iterate over the children of `.CricketPlayers`, pull the `text` out of each `<li>`, split on `,` (and hope there are no other commas), iterate over *those* and split on `:` and use each pair as a property name/value. This is why web scraping is awful--can you just get the data instead?

Comment: @DaveNewton I can start formatting it as JSON when data is entered, but it can be deleted and then deleting it from that variable is even more difficult.

Comment: It shouldn't be; you have a unique ID and/or a linear collection, so updating or deleting should be (reasonably) straight-forward.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
let result = [];
let parent = document.querySelector(".CricketPlayers").children;
Array.prototype.forEach.call(parent, child => {
  let x = child.innerHTML.split(",");
  let y = JSON.stringify(x).replace("[","{").replace("]","}");
  result.push(y)
});
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('.CricketPlayers li')]
.map(node => node.innerText.match(/Player\: (\w+). TotalRuns\: (.*). AllRounder\: (.*)/))
.map(matchedParts => ({ Player: matchedParts ? matchedParts[1] : '', TotalRuns: matchedParts ? matchedParts[2] : 0, AllRounder: matchedParts ? matchedParts[3] : 0 }))
```

and the results are like yours.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please show the output? When I `console.log` the whole thing, I did not see the result as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Get the children of the `ol`, iterate them and construct the array.

```js
let ol = document.getElementsByClassName('CricketPlayers');


let output =[...ol[0].children].map(item => {

   let props = item.innerHTML.split(',');
   
   return props.reduce((a, c) => {   
   
      aProp = c.split(':');    
      a[aProp[0].trim()] = aProp[1].trim();    
      return a
    
   }, {})

})

console.log(output)
```

```html
<ol class="CricketPlayers">
    <li id="1">Player: John, TotalRuns: 4350, AllRounder: false</li>
    <li id="2">Player: Michael, TotalRuns: 8373, AllRounder: true</li>
</ol>
```